# C++ Redis hiredis compiler error?

Tags: c++, redis

Thanks to someone on this site, I was able to use a sample C++ source file.
https://gist.github.com/1893378
When I compile this, I get a bunch of strange compiler errors:

```
/home/.../workspace/redis-hiredis-3c46b13/pipelineTest.cpp: In function ‘void redisTop(redisContext*)’:
/home/.../workspace/redis-hiredis-3c46b13/pipelineTest.cpp:142:32: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘redisReply*’
/home/../workspace/redis-hiredis-3c46b13/pipelineTest.cpp:162:25: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’
/home/=.../workspace/redis-hiredis-3c46b13/pipelineTest.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
```

I realize I may be out of synch with hiredis libray but I am using the latest one. Any ideas how to properly build this C++ program?

Also, I am looking for a complete C++ tutorial of pipeline with Redis. Here is a really good example in Java:

http://www.cafebabe.me/2011/05/redis-pipelines-and-transactions.html

Is there no example tutorial like this for C++?
Thanks either way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it is a C program, not C++. The C++ compiler is usually more pedantic that a C compiler, and it complains. Minor adaptations are needed to compile with a C++ compiler.

I did them, and put the file online again:
https://gist.github.com/1893378

It now compiles fine with g++ 3.4 and 4.3

AFAIK, there is no C++ tutorial for Redis. I think the best way to deal with Redis in C++ is to develop your own wrapping classes on top of hiredis. It is not that hard.

Comment: Hmmm. I am still getting strange error of unresolved errors but maybe it is just me. I have not looked at c or c++ in many many years. Thanks anyhow.

Comment: Attached Makefile and compilation lines to the gist

Comment: Whoa! This is so helpful for us newbies or those that have not looked at c++ in many years. Thanks so much! I got it working thanks to you!!

Answer (score 2):

Just cast redisCommand to redisReply

```
reply = (redisReply *)redisCommand(context, "PING");
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a C program. You have to build it with a C compiler.